# asp.net dropdownlist caching for Huge data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have to bind nearly 50k records to my asp.net dropdownlist and it has to be searchable. What is the best way to do implement it . Are there any caching techniques so that the list loads as we scroll?Appreciate the suggestions.

Please advise.

Comment: To don't implement it. 50k items in a DropDownList is a bad idea. Not to mention it will slow the page down both in loading and user responsiveness. Better use some sort of ajax solution or do some categorizing (1st dropdown selection is the filter for the second etc)

Comment: Had the same situation. Go with select2 , it made everything easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by use of web service.

first of all add following code in your aspx page.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="" id="tbCountries" />
</div>
```

Now, Create your Web service using following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.>WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> ShowCountryList(string sLookUP)
    {
        List<string> lstCountries = new List<string>();

        string sConnString = "Data Source=DNA;Persist Security Info=False;" +
            "Initial Catalog=DNA_CLASSIFIED;User Id=sa;Password=;Connect Timeout=30;";

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(sConnString);
        SqlCommand objComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT CountryName FROM Country " + 
            "WHERE CountryName LIKE '%'+@LookUP+'%' ORDER BY CountryName", myConn);
        myConn.Open();

        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LookUP", sLookUP);
        SqlDataReader reader = objComm.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            lstCountries.Add(reader["CountryName"].ToString());
        }
        myConn.Close();  return lstCountries;
    }
}
```

Finally, Create jquery Method for bind Textbox with webservice,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        BindControls();
    });

    function BindControls() {
        $("#tbListOfCountries").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/ShowCountryList",
                    data: "{ 'sLookUP': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                            return { value: item }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1    // MINIMUM 1 CHARACTER TO START WITH.
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend taking advantage of jQuery's autocomplete plugin:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

It's configurable and has autocomplete search out of the box. It can also consume your remote data source (though you might consider a paginated API response):

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Answer (score 2):

In the backend, create a `controller action` (if you are using ASP.NET MVC) or a `page method` (if you're using ASP.NET Web Forms) that receives a `searchTerm` parameter and returns an array of the top (say, 100) results.

In the frontend, use a **typeahead** / **autocomplete** plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead). When the user sets the search term, perform an Ajax request against the backend and display the results. When performing the [Ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can also enable and configure caching. No more optimization shall be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use AutoComplete textbox and set datasource from remote API especially when working with huge dataset. This will avoid your application UI getting hanged on every character search.

Ref the Link: https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

Answer (score 0):

depends on where the list items are coming from. 
if they are coming from a list or database just append them then use javascript to search the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartment" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" />            
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>       

        $(function () {

            $("[id$=txtDepartment]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "FetchDropdownList.aspx/GetDepartment",
                        data: "{'departmentName':'" + document.getElementById('txtDepartment').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item.Name
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });        
    </script>
</body>
</html>

public class Department
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        private static List<Department> GetDepartment()
        {
            List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                Department department = new Department();
                department.Id = i;
                department.Name = "Department " + i.ToString();
                departments.Add(department);
            }
            return departments;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static List<Department> GetDepartment(string departmentName)
        {            
            int totalDepartments = GetDepartment().Count;
            List<Department> departments = GetDepartment().Where(d => d.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(departmentName.ToLower())).Take(20).ToList();

            return departments;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem like you and I used **[RadAutoCompleteBox](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx)**. It has many 
client-side and server-side events that help you to handle various situations. It's very comfortable for ASP.NET projects.

Answer (score 0):

I see two immediate solution for this.

1. As other has suggested usign ajax to search related item as user types and show them.
2. On page load get all your data and store them in javascript variable then you can perform search on that variable as user types and bind search result to dropdown list.

Similar to [this one](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache):

Answer (score 0):

Definitely any Autocomplete implementation will work in your scenario.

**Solution 1:** Use Autocomplete select box

- If you don’t want to waste bandwidth or want to support devices with
  low specification, you should go for AutoComplete with server side
  data fetching.
- If you want **high usability** and don’t care about the bandwidth,
  you can use autocomplete with local data (Fetch 50k records one time
  and bind to the autocomplete). But to make sure that you don’t paint
  all these into DOM at a single time. **You need to limit the records
  being shown at a particular time.**

**Solution 2** : Use select with virtualization

- But if you want to give the **best of the usability to your
  clients**, you should go with a solution where your select box is
  **virtualized** and the data loaded into `DOM` on scrolling of the select box. By **virtualization** you are making sure that only those
  items are getting pushed to **DOM** which are being shown in the
  screen at that point of time.

  You can find a jQuery based virtual select [here](https://github.com/sergi/virtual-list)

  Similar implementation in React [here](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized-select/)

  [image]